# Missing uv textures

Tags: texture-painting

So trying to get this wolf I did finished but I can't paint on it as it keeps saying missing uv maps! Any help please with this?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In order to paint on a 3d object,first **Uv maps and paint/texture layers need to be created and saved** and only then one can paint on it.There are many other ways to do this but the one below, is by far the simplest.

I am demonstrating the procedure on this monkey ,you can follow the same steps on for your  model.

**1** .After creating/adding monkey in object mode, **select the monkey and  switch to texture mode**.Also open a side window and **open the Uv/Image editor**.
**2** . Once in texture mode -tools panel(T),click   on  **add simple Uv's** button.This will **create a Uv map** of the object in Uv/Image editor. Save this Uv map as a Png on your computer by clicking Image->New Image->Create 1024x1024 png.
**3**.Going back to 3dview,click on **Paint Slot dropdown menu** and select the type of Paint Slot you want.For general purpose,**DiffuseColor =1024x1024** should suffice .
[image]

**4**.**Save these newly created Uv map and Paint Slot/layer as a Png Image** by going to the Uv/Image editor ->Image->Save as Image.This is done by individually selecting the Uv map and Paint layer from the Dropdown menu.
[image]

**5**.Start **Painting** by going to the texture paint -tools panel and under brushes selecting the **TexDraw brush** and the required color.  [image]

**6**.**IMPORTANT** -Save the Paint layer frequently as **Blender does not Autosave**.

Comment: That's different from my blender

Comment: Even if Blender version's are different ,the procedure is the SAME.Simply go to textures panel (top) with your model selected and follow the above steps.You should be able to get the above shown results.

Answer (score 0):

To texture paint, you need to set up a material, an image texture, and a UV map.

[image]

To make Ctrl+T work Node Wrangler add-on should be enabled.

[image]