# Missing UVs, Detected!

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

I'm trying to texture paint a character in Blender, and I am loosely following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vTYustK-XBk), just so I know what I'm doing. So this is what I've done:

1. Went to the Texture Paint tab.
2. Created a new material (on my character) and then in Base Color, clicked on the dot on the right side and then clicked Image Texture. I then created a new texture with the size of 2048px.
3. In Object Mode, I clicked on the Shading arrow on the right, near all the viewport shading buttons, and then clicked Flat.
4. (This was either step 3 or 4,) but I saved the texture and placed it near my .blend file.

That's where I stopped, because it gave me the warning. This is the current screenshot of what the editor looks right now:

[image: Blender Warning.]

I've searched on the net already, and saw [this article](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160401/missing-uv-textures), but the suggestions weren't really helpful.

Also in the same question, I was wondering how the person got this:

[image: Unwrap]

Menu to show, as the GIF was to fast for me to catch it.

Also I have seen these questions:

1. [I am not able to use texture paint (2.8)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/163797/i-am-not-able-to-use-texture-paint-2-8)
2. [missing files blender 2.82 Missing UVs, Textures, detected!](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/176446/missing-files-blender-2-82-missing-uvs-textures-detected?answertab=votes#tab-top)

But none of those worked. In the question number 2, I did try to change mode to Single Image, but nothing worked.

[image: In Mode]

Maybe I'm changing it in the wrong place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've finally fixed the problem in the answer to this [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/176446/missing-files-blender-2-82-missing-uvs-textures-detected?answertab=votes#tab-top). I needed to click Add UVs and then upload the (blank) texture I had.

In the tool bar, I clicked Draw and then it gave me the options to paint the character.

However, I had another problem, which is that when I try to paint my character, the paint did not show. I fixed it by [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75662/texture-paints-brush-is-always-black?rq=1).